# Keyframe animation to slide element in from outside the bounds of the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I would like to have a key frame animation where the element slides in from beyond the bounds of it's parent element.

I've been using this to slide an element from left to right:

```
@keyframes slide-right {

    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

}
```

But that only slides the element in from 100% to the left of it's final position.

I'd like it to slide in from directly off screen from it's parent element. You can see an example of what I have working here that shows the current behavior (not the desired behavior).

```css
@keyframes slide-right {

  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

}
#Menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 105px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 324px;
    top: 114px;
    animation: 0.3s ease-out 0s 1 normal forwards running slide-right;
}
.Rectangle_491 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100px;
    height: 105px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#Rectangle_491 {
  fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  stroke: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 300px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div id="Menu" onclick="application.goBack()" style="display: block; animation: 0.3s ease-out 0s 1 normal forwards running slide-right;">
    <svg class="Rectangle_491">
      <rect id="Rectangle_491" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="105">
      </rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

One idea I have is to find the keyframe style declaration (if possible) and manually set the translateX() position in pixels or percent using the width of the parent element but I'd prefer to see if it's possible in CSS before going to a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try setting `.main` to `overflow: hidden` and positioning the `#Menu` outside of that parent:

```css
@keyframes slide-right {

    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

}

main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5pc;
  outline: 2px solid lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1pc;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #222;
  animation: slide-right 0.3s normal forwards running;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
</main>
```